# Can anyone solve this error in JdbcTemlate?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Can anyone solve this error in **Spring** using `JdbcTemplate`.
Here is the Error-

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.setMinIdle(I)V
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionPool(BasicDataSource.java:1496)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionPool(BasicDataSource.java:1496)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
at com.spring.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.updateSal(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:26)
at com.spring.test.SpringTestCase.main(SpringTestCase.java:20)
```

Comment: We would need to see your code, not just the error

Comment: Looks like you have a Problem with a wrong Version of `commons-pool`. Can you show wich spring version and which version of `commons-pool do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You are using Apache Commons DBCP, which has a transitive dependency on Apache Commons Pool. You have a mismatch between the version of Commons Pool your DBCP dependency needs, and the actual version of Commons Pool on your classpath.

Alternatively, you have *two* versions of Commons Pool on the classpath, the right one occurring later.

If you are using Maven to build your project, then run

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to diagnose the source of your problem.